# Dealing with ScrollViews in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I want to draw a border around a ScrollView in my Kivy app. The problem is that the content of the ScrollView overlap that border since I'm drawing it inside the widget.
So I'm wondering if one of those is a possible solution:

- How can I draw outside the widget's boundaries?
  When I tried to move a part of a canvas element outside the widget, it simply cut off that part, which is no surprise. Perhaps I could make another widget outside this one and draw on it?
- How can I limit the content of the ScrollView? So, can I change the scroll boundaries? What I mean is that I don't want the children to go beyond a certain point in the widget to make them not touch the border

Here is some test code to demonstrate the issue. It's a slightly modified official example. The buttons overlap the green border when scrolling, which is what I don't want:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

Builder.load_string('''
<ScrollView>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 1, 0, 1
        Line:
            points: self.x, self.y + self.height,\
            self.x + self.width, self.y + self.height,\
            self.x + self.width, self.y, self.x, self.y,\
            self.x, self.y + self.height
            width: 1.2
''')

class TestApp(App):                
    def build(self):
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=10, spacing=10,
                            size_hint=(None, None), width=500)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
        for i in range(30):
            btn = Button(text=str(i), size=(480, 40),
                         size_hint=(None, None))
            layout.add_widget(btn)

        root = ScrollView(size_hint=(None, None), size=(500, 320),
                          pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}, do_scroll_x=False)
        root.add_widget(layout)
        return root

TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I draw outside the widget's boundaries?
>   When I tried to move a part of a canvas element outside the widget, it simply cut off that part, which is no surprise. Perhaps I could make another widget outside this one and draw on it?

<s>Don't really have a clue what you mean by it.</s> `canvas` has no boundaries, except if you use `Stencil`. When you try to draw outside of `ScrollView`, content out of the widget's space will be hidden, because originally it uses `Stencil` so that the unnecessary content is hidden and you could scroll through it as you can see [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/scrollview.py#L136).

Now about that overlaping. `canvas.after` before the second `Color` makes it draw after the widgets are drawn. Similar to `canvas.before`, which is used for backgrounds.

```
canvas:
    Color:
        rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
    Rectangle:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
canvas.after:
    ...
```

Basic `canvas` is drawn in the "same" time as the widgets are, therefore the item that is drawn later will be on the top no matter what you do. `after` will draw after all is drawn again with that order and `before` does the same thing before the widgets are even drawn at all.

> How can I limit the content of the ScrollView? So, can I change the scroll boundaries? What I mean is that I don't want the children to go beyond a certain point in the widget to make them not touch the border

Use layout with fixed size that handles it's children's pos e.g. `FloatLayout` with `pos_hint` or `BoxLayout` depends on your need, therefore it will push the widgets inside to imaginary rectangle, which is basically [0, 0] to [width, height] i.e. size of your layout(if you use it right).

Comment: Yes, I've wanted to draw outside the `ScrollView`. When I tried to draw a line outside, it simply didn't appear. I don't think it really matters now since the solution with `canvas.after` worked just like I wanted it to